# HTML5 User Saved Column Widths

Tags: html, deprecated

According to [w3.org](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/col.html) the `width` attribute of `col` tags is obsolete.  Their suggestion to "use css," however, doesn't work when you want to programatically change column widths.

Use case: User changes column widths.  I save that layout in localstorage.  User logs back in, I pull that layout from localstorage and....?

If I were the sort to ignore the standards I'd just go ahead and set the `td` or `col` width attribute.  What should I do instead?

#### Note: as is usually the case with stack overflow, the act of writing the question revelaed the answer....I feel a bit dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `width` attribute, use a `style` attribute with a value for `width`.